# Kan extensions and double application of Yoneda lemma

Tags: category-theory

If we are given functors
$$
F: \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}, \\
G: \mathcal{B} \to \mathcal{C}, \\
H: \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{C},
$$
the natural transformations
$$
\alpha: H \to GF
$$
are in bijective correspondence to mappings
$$
\alpha^\prime: \mathcal{C}(GB,C) \to [\mathcal{A}^{op},\mathrm{Set}](\mathcal{B}(F{-},B),\mathcal{C}(H{-},C))
$$
natural in $B$ and $C$. When $\alpha^\prime$ is a bijection, $G$ is the left Kan extension of $H$ along $F$.

I think I am deeply non-understanding something basic; the bijective correspondence between transformations $\alpha$ and $\alpha^\prime$ is said to come from a "double application of Yoneda lemma". I couldn't find out how to use Yoneda lemma to prove this. Could you help please? (I know Yoneda lemma and its proof.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Yoneda lemma, maps
$$\mathcal{C} (G B, C) \to [\mathcal{A}^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Set}] (\mathcal{B} (F -, B), \mathcal{C} (H -, C))$$
that are natural in $C$ correspond to elements of $[\mathcal{A}^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Set}] (\mathcal{B} (F -, B), \mathcal{C} (H -, G B))$, i.e. maps
$$\mathcal{B} (F A, B) \to \mathcal{C} (H A, G B)$$
that are natural in $A$. On the other hand, naturality in $B$ means that such maps correspond to elements of $\mathcal{C} (H A, G F A)$, i.e. morphisms
$$H A \to G F A$$
as claimed.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had problems to come up with this starting with the map $HA \to GFA$. Going the other way seems somehow easier.

Comment: It's usually easier to simplify a complicated expression than to make a complicated expression from a simple one.